# Dependências da Lib em C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Estou fazendo umas lib em C# para utilizar nos meus projetos e não ter sempre que reescrever. porém como eu faço com as dependências da Lib?

*Exemplo:*

Fiz uma lib para utilizar o Google Drive e tem o nome `lib.GoogleDrive` porém precisa ir junto:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.dll
Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc4.dll
```

**Qual seria a forma mais inteligente de usar a lib?**

Adicionar o projeto da **lib** no projeto que vai usar ela ou fazer rotina para publicar a minha `DLL` com as `DLL` de dependência?

ou

**Utilizar o Nugget e fazer um pacote com as dependências**?

Comment: Acredito que o **Nuget** sirva melhor para o seu caso. Você monta o seu pacote com todas as dependências e ao baixar o pacote já vem tudo certo

Answer (score 0):

O correto é o seguinte:

Faça a sua `Lib` particular e adicione as dependências no seu projeto, após isso, o seu projeto para funcionar precisa que as dependências estejam presentes, mas, cada mantenedor de biblioteca é responsável pela sua atualização, ou seja, se foi adicionado uma dependência e ela for atualizada a sua `lib` também precisa acontecer essa atualização (*não é obrigatório, mas, por motivos de `bugs` e correções é bom manter os projetos atualizados*) e uma nova publicação com essas mudanças devem ocorrer.

Resumindo cada projeto e suas atualizações é de responsabilidade do mantenedor da biblioteca e são independentes.

No ***Visual Studio 2017***, por exemplo é fácil fazer bibliotecas e adicionar os pacotes de dependência, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nessa biblioteca de exemplo tem uma dependencia com o pacote [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json), sendo que o seu projeto depende dela para funcionar, mas, são projetos mantidos por usuários diferentes e cada uma recebe atualizações de acordo com a suas necessidades.

Para configurar a geração desse pacote clique no projeto com o botão direito e no menu propriedades abre a seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e clique selecione o item *Generate Nuget package on build* para geração do pacote e suas dependencias quando o projeto for gerado.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abrindo esse pacote no [Nuget Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) verifica que foi adicionado a dependencia como esperado.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]